# Unable to load the manifest for package <package_name>

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone.

I walked through the tutorials and created a custom message called "Person.msg" under a project named "testing". I can *see* the message and its definition using "rosmsg show". I can also publish data using the message definition and with a subscriber see the data being published.

So with that said, here is my issue. I have a rosbridge server running and have had success connecting, advertising, publishing, and subscribing to *preexisting* message types (ex: std_msgs/String). However, when I try to simply *subscribe* to my custom message type, I get an error displayed in rosbridge which states:

*"subscribe: Unable to load the manifest for package testing. Caused by: testing"*

My manifest file in the testing package is as follows

```
<package>
  <description brief="testing">

        testing
  </description>
  <author>James</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>"couldnt post the url..."</url>
  <depend package="std_msgs"/>
  <depend package="rospy"/>
  <depend package="roscpp"/> </package>
```

Anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62072/unable-to-load-the-manifest-for-package-%3Cpackage_name%3E/) by [Souldier](https://answers.ros.org/users/4820/souldier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2013-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. No harm no foul. Looks like I just needed to close out the rosbridge terminal window and restart it. I guess it was having trouble "seeing" the new project..

---

Originally posted by [Souldier](https://answers.ros.org/users/4820/souldier/) with karma: 198 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1